# how to redirect to specific file by writing rule in .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have developed a project without using any framework. I want to redirect a page to specific php file (example : movie/movie.php) when click on this

```
 <a href="/movie/1/Baashha-Suresh-Krishna-1995">Click me</a>
```

link. I have created .htaccess file and currently it look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^/movie/([0-9]+)/$ http://localhost/tthtml/movie/movie_review.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have enable mod_rewrite module in httpd.conf file. I am using wamp server in windows machine.

I dont no how to do this. I have referenced few sites and I created this above rule in my own. Kindly any one help me to do this and feel better if your answer have explonation as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the rule as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://localhost/tthtml/movie/movie_review.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

The rule that you placed was not working because it was comparing only  the string "/movie/1/", while you actually want to match "/movie/1/Baashha-Suresh-Krishna-1995".

For this to work, I have modified the RewriteRule directive as `^/movie/([0-9]+)/(.*)$` to accommodate the remaining string "Baashha-Suresh-Krishna-1995" or any other value that the application may have.

Comment: the leading slash is automatically matched by RewriteRule function on htaccess context.